# Find the distribution of a statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sample

I'm trying to solve the next excercise.

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ iid random variables with pdf
> $$f(x,\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(x+1)^{\theta+1}}, x>0$$
> with a parameter $\theta>0.$
>
> Find the distribution of the statistic $T$ given by
> $$T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1+X_i)$$

In my attempt I got stuck:

> $\begin{align}P[T<x]&=P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1+X_i)< x\right]\\
> &=P\left[e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1+X_i)}< e^x\right]\\
> &=P\left[\prod_{i=1}^n(1+X_i)< e^x\right]
> \end{align}$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it.

Comment: With the domain presently stated your PDF is not valid (integrates to infinity, not one).  Please fix this aspect of your question.

Comment: Discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373783/119261.